# How to remove a drop down list zend framework ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, zend-framework, drop-down-menu

I'm working with zend framework ,and i have to remove a drop down list ,after clicking on a button.I recuperate the drop down list from the FORM : $task.
PS :I added a link which can add a drop down list with ajax ,but i can't do the same the work with the remove.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework is a server-side language, which means it's not suitable for making modifications to the document in the browser. Instead, use javascript or javascript plus a javascript framework. I suggest you look into jQuery.

If you go down the jQuery route, try using something like this:

```
$('#the-id-of-your-list').remove ()
```